# EF Core 6 Get nextval from oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, sequence

In EF Core 6 you can map a sequence and use it on a mapped entity.

Sequence mapping

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder b)
 {
     b.HasSequence<int>("seq_certificate_trade_request", "ts");
 }
```

I just need the next sequence value and don't have a type that are using it.

Today I am using the following code

```
public int GetNewCertificateTradeRequestIdentity()
{
    using var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ts.seq_certificate_trade_request.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL";
    _context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    return reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

But it would be nice to get ride of the code an used something build in to EF6

So can I call the sequence seq_certificate_trade_request directly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No unfortunately. Maybe in EF7 (:

Comment: I found a solution. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141223/oracle-sequence-ef-core-6-0/72153481#72153481

Comment: From Microsoft documentation here (here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences), it should be possible to customize the `OnModelCreating()` method to have the next value automatically be recovered from the sequence when needed (e.g. during `INSERT` operation).
But I was not able to have it work.

Comment: Thanks maybe it works for SQL Server but I can't get it to work with Oracle